# What happens if you have more than one Stalker mark?

Tags: warframe

So, I was farming parts when I got marked by the Stalker, twice. Does this make him able to spawn twice in one mission?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Stalker can only be spawned once per mission, this is the same with every boss that has a random chance to spawn (I know this by personal experience). Just as a side note I cannot find any evidence of the marks spawn chance stacking, but the marks themselves will stack so you'll always get as many stalkers as you have marks.